# Handling Error while sending sms in twilio

Tags: laravel, twilio

I've an order table, where user input some details with phone number. When user confirm the order, i'm sending sms to that phone number using twilio programmable sms. The sms sending is working fine. Here is the code:

```
    $message = $twilio->messages
                      ->create($toNumber, [
                            'body' => 'My Message',
                            'from' => 'AlphaNumericNumber'
                        ]);
```

But the problem is if user typed an invalid number, it is throwing a HTTP 400 code error. I want to show a user friendly flash/error message back to form if user typed invalid number. Can anyone help me with this? I'm using laravel 5.5 on my application.

The Error I'm getting:

```
Twilio \ Exceptions \ RestException (21211)
    [HTTP 400] Unable to create record: The 'To' number is not a valid phone number.
```

Comment: are you able to get error 400/ success 200 if yes then put these in if else Session::flash('message', 'This is a message!'); 
Session::flash('alert-class', 'alert-danger');

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can wrap your twilio call in a try..catch statement, with a redirect on error:

```
try {
    $message = $twilio->messages
                      ->create($toNumber, [
                          'body' => 'My Message',
                          'from' => 'AlphaNumericNumber'
                       ]);

} catch (\Exception $e) {
    // will return user to previous screen with twilio error
    return redirect()->back()->withError($e->getMessage());
}
```

If an exception is encountered, the user is redirected to the previous screen with details of the error stored in flash.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I did also used try catch statement. but the error was in namespace. I was using RestException and the namespace wasn't right. Thats why it was giving error. and wasn't catching the exception error. And your solution was also corrent. Same as mine.

Comment: My version is designed to catch any exception, regardless of namespace. I wasn't aware that you used try...catch as it was missing from your question. In the future, please try and include all the relevant code.

Comment: @AlauddinAhmed which namespace is correct?